# Add one hour to string on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have two timepicker in my view

```
  @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m=>m.AttendeeStartTime).Format("HH:mm")
  @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m=>m.AttendeeEndTime).Format("HH:mm")
```

This is how it looks
[image]

and here is rendered HTML for From Timepicker,

```
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The AttendeeStartTime field is required." 
id="AttendeeStartTime" name="AttendeeStartTime" type="text" value="09:00" data-role="timepicker" 
class="k-input valid" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-
owns="AttendeeStartTime_timeview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="width: 100%;">
```

Whenever there is change in From timepicker, how can I add one hour to its value and set to to To timepicker?
This is what I have done,

```
  $('#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AttendeeStartTime)').on('change', function () {
        //var date = new Date();
        endTime.value($(this).val());
        alert(endTime.value());
```

This only sets the To value to the same as From when there is change, but I want to add an hour or some timespan to it.

How should i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AttendeeStartTime)').on('change', function () {        
    //try getting the date from the date picker
    var date = $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AttendeeStartTime)").data("kendoTimePicker").value();
    if (date) {
       //convert the string to a date
       date = new Date(date); //you can probably skip this step since the Kendo DatePicker returns a Date object
       //increase the "hours"                               
       date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
       //set it back in the "to" date picker
       $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AttendeeEndTime)").data("kendoTimePicker").value(date);
       //alert(endTime.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: console error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'value'`

Comment: @Biplov13, yeah, sorry about that. I'm used to getting the Kendo objects through the API and not directly from the DOM, which is what I strongly recommend you to also do. It's somewhat safer, as it gets the format according to the documentation and you can use the [existing methods](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/timepicker). I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks it also works without the line `date = new Date(date); ` as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function like this,

```
function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
  function z(n){ return (n<10? '0':'') + n;};
  var bits = time.split(':');
  var mins = bits[0]*60 + +bits[1] + +minsToAdd;

  return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60);  
}  

addMinutes('05:40', '20');  // '06:00'
addMinutes('23:50', 20);
```

Your scenario should be,

```
 $('#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AttendeeStartTime)').on('change', function () {
        //var date = new Date();
        endTime.value($(this).val());
        addMinutes($(this).val(), '60');
        alert(endTime.value());
```